# What are the different types of uniformities in subjects?

Tags: metaphysics

Some I can think of:
- Uniformity of law (uniformities that are found in nature)

- Uniformities in interpretation (uniformity in how we 'interpret' mathematical findings or works of art)
- Uniformity of motive (once again, with reference to art, the intentions of artist, are they uniform?)

How do we define uniformities in areas of knowledge? I personally think that the concept of uniformities is multifaceted, and doesn't have a single one line definition? What do you think?

By uniformities in areas of knowledge, I am referring to the assumption of uniformities when studying / enhancing knowledge in various subjects.

Comment: Welcome to the forum, Selena. It would probably help if you could elaborate a little on the target concept: can you describe and/or exemplify what you have in mind when you speak of ‘uniformities in areas of knowledge’? Relatedly, what exactly do you mean by the uniformity of law / interpretation / motive, and is there anything these types of uniformity have in common, in your opinion?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I’m afraid I still don’t get it. Could you supply a concrete example of, say, a case where mathematical findings are (not) interpreted with uniformity? An example of an ‘assumption of uniformities when studying’ would also be helpful.

Comment: Honestly, I am myself confused. Since mathematics is an idealisation of the empirical findings (in nature, Galileo states that book of nature is written in maths), we would assume uniformities, which is why we use mathematical induction to prove conjectures in maths, and also mathematical theorems are based on axioms, which are also mere assumptions of uniformity.

Comment: A counter example in maths is hence difficult to find unless I give reference to Hume's problem of induction, however then too, maths does not employ inductive reasoning but deductive reasoning, so referencing Hume wouldn't make sense, I suppose.

Comment: Nevertheless, a counter example could be the following: when we use proof by mathematical induction to prove conjectures,  we assume that if the conjecture works for when n=1, n=k, and n=k+1, it must work for all n values where n is an integer. This, however, is an assumption since we do not try substitute all values of n into the conjecture (essentially a theorem after 'proof') to see if the conjecture is actually true for all values of n.

Comment: Another counter example for maths could maybe be the discrepancy theory or an example from variation calculus.

Comment: Not sure mathematical induction *assumes* uniformity: it *exploits* it. Induction is a **conditional**: If (P(0) and [if P(n), then P(n+1)]), then for all n, P(n). You don’t assume that P(n) implies P(n+1); proving that is usually the crux of a proof by induction. If you take a look at an introduction to set theory, like Jech’s or Halmos’, it’ll give you an idea of how much uniformity is ‘built into’ the numbers, and how much ‘falls out’. If you’re more interested in non-mathematical induction, this is a good article: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/

Comment: @MarkOxford. Induction assumes uniformity in the sense that the truth of whatever results from induction assumes the truth of uniformity. If there were no uniformity, induction would fall to the ground.

Comment: @PédeLeão you mean mathematical induction does assume uniformity, right?

Comment: @SelenaCarlos. I mean induction *in general*, including mathematics. In the example that Mark gave, the validity of P(n+1) assumes that there is a successor to n to which it makes sense to apply the function P; that is, successive values of n are assumed to be *uniform*.

Comment: @PédeLeão this is what I initially thought :))) Thank you so much for the clarification

Comment: Yes there is a need for these fixed ideas, or forms. Artists can use them, say as signs (semiotics) or they can play off of them and use them as a melodramatic cliche (Douglas Sirk was a master of this in film). Many uses, the artists can mock these fixed ideas too, but they need them:  they would cry if they disappeared. Big subject. Film studies alone will keep you busy.

Comment: Even in film editing you can see this uniformity, the fixed idea, or "way".  You know the Hollywood style of the Golden age, the polish, narrative style, the way they were edited,  and the Italians and French played off this (against it) to great effect.

Comment: @Gordon what would be an example of semiotics in melodramatic cliche. Are you referring to emotions or maybe exaggerated emotions and sensationalism? I like your point and would like to expand on it :)

Comment: http://filmalert101.blogspot.com/2017/06/bruce-hodsdon-on-cinema-of-douglas-sirk.html?m=1@SelenaCarlos  The cute baby deer in the window!  It's too cute. "The Happy Ending" that never is.  One of Sirk's films. You may want to read up on Sirk. No you don't have time. Do a Wikipedia on Douglas Sirk. The fixed idea is fake bourgeois happiness that Sirk plays against. I.e. It masks real loneliness and isolation.

Comment: @SelenaCarlos The above is in response to your question. The uniformity is the fixed idea (Plato).  Something must remain steady, an idea or way of doing things. We use it, or we make fun of it, react off of it. How do we use it and/or play against it.

Comment: Yeh I know :)) Thank you so much for the example!! :)